# THREE.JS : How to correctly use a normal map with a Toon Material (if possible)?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I'm curently working on a 3D viewer with Three.js on my website for JavaScript learning and demonstration of some 3d works with GLTFLoader and Blender objects.
The viewer is basic and run as intended but i wanted to try to replace the StandardMaterial of the gltf object to a ToonMaterial. From the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshToonMaterial) i figured that i can use a normal map but i'm unable to render it correctly.

Here two pictures of a test object with the materials behaviours:
[standard material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNHDw.jpg)
[toon material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/832ho.jpg)

Here is my process:

1. save the initial material of the object in a variable.
2. create a new MeshToonMaterial and assign the maps from the initial material.
3. assign the toon material to the object.

The process works but the light don't follow anymore the normal map.
Excerpts from the code:

```
/* ... */
let initialMaterial = '';
const threeTone = new THREE.DataTexture(
    Uint8Array.from([0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 255, 255, 255]),3,1,THREE.RGBFormat
);
/* ... function called by an onclick event to swap materials */
function toonAssign(){
    scene.traverse( function ( child, ) {
        if ( child.isMesh ) {
            if (child.material.type == 'MeshToonMaterial') {
                child.material = initialMaterial;
            }
            else {
                let oldMaterial = child.material;
                let toonMaterial = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
                    gradientMap: threeTone,
                    map: oldMaterial.map,
                    normalMap: oldMaterial.normalMap
                });
                child.material = toonMaterial;
                child.material.needsUpdate = true;
            }
        }
    } );
}
/* ... initial material come from the gltf object here */
let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(manager);
loader.load( modelName + '.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child.isMesh ) {
            child.castShadow = true;
            child.receiveShadow = true;
            defaultMaterial = child.material;
            child.material.needsUpdate = true;
        }
    } );
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
} );
/* ... */
```

I surely missing something, because the normal map is showing and partially working but it seems the tangents aren't used the right way or something like that.

I'm a rookie with Three.js and i can't find any tips with the combination of 'three.js','toon material' and 'normal map' so i don't kown what to do or if that's just not possible or anything.

Any help will be usefull, tell me if i miss something to explain.